# Export to Excel, PDF, CSV file doesn't support Arabic Language

Tags: jsp, tomcat, localization, export

I have tomcat6 and use open report application in it.
when i export any report as excel or pdf, it doesn't support arabic language.
Please can anyone help me? 
you can find below jsp page code.

---

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display" %>
<%@page import="org.efs.openreports.util.DisplayProperty"%>
<%@page import="org.efs.openreports.objects.Report"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<s:include value="Banner.jsp" />
<s:if test="report == null || !report.isDisplayInline()">

<a class="back-link img-report-small" href="reportList.action"><s:text name="link.back.reports"/></a>
<a class="back-link img-group-small" href="reportGroup.action"><s:text name="link.back.groups"/></a>    

<br/>

<s:actionerror/>
    <div align="center">  
        <div class="important img-queryreport" id="instructions"><s:property value="report.name"/></div>  
    </div>
</s:if>

<div align="center">   

  <s:set name="results" value="results" scope="request" />  
  <s:set name="properties" value="properties" scope="request" />
  <s:set name="report" value="report" scope="request" />
  <% DisplayProperty[] displayProperties = (DisplayProperty[]) request.getAttribute("properties");
     request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     Report report = (Report) request.getAttribute("report");%>

  <display:table name="results" class="displayTag" sort="list" export="true" pagesize="20" requestURI="queryReportResult.action?tab=PRODUCTIVITY" excludedParams="org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN">  
    <% for (int i=0; i < displayProperties.length; i++) { %>
      <display:column property="<%=displayProperties[i].getName()%>" title="<%=displayProperties[i].getDisplayName()%>" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" />
    <% } %>
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true"/> 
    <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="<%=report.getName() + ".xml"%>"/>
    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="<%=report.getName() + ".pdf"%>"/>
    <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="<%=report.getName() + ".csv"%>"/>
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="<%=report.getName() + ".xls"%>"/>
  </display:table>


  <s:if test="#session.user.scheduler">

    <s:text name="queryReport.scheduleReport"/>
    <a href="reportOptions.action?reportId=<%=report.getId()%>&submitSchedule=true&exportType=3">CSV</a> |
    <a href="reportOptions.action?reportId=<%=report.getId()%>&submitSchedule=true&exportType=1">Excel</a> |
    <a href="reportOptions.action?reportId=<%=report.getId()%>&submitSchedule=true&exportType=0">PDF</a>

  </s:if>  

</div>

<s:if test="report == null || !report.isDisplayInline()">

<s:include value="Footer.jsp" />

</s:if>
```

---

help me quickly please...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't support Arabic"? Are characters corrupted? Text direction is wrong? Something else? "help me quickly" does not work here very well, especially when information you provide is insufficient...

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue under **JBoss** using **Displaytag 1.2** picked from a **Stripes** MVC application.

When the database (MySQL) was giving strings containing **Scandinavian language characters encoded in UTF-8**, then the CSV and Excel exporting of those tables was corrupted i.e. the downloaded file contained no data or a small amount of useless corrupted data.

I think the main issue, data related, was regarding **Finnish characters' encodings** which are in ISO-8859-1 but not in UTF-8 (cfr. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

The fix that is working for me was to:

1. adding this to the Stripes Action Bean:

   ```
   getContext().getResponse().setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   getContext().getResponse().setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8");
   ```
2. adding this to the corresponding JSP:

   ```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
   ```

After this I am succesfully able to download CSV and Excel files from a Displaytag table containing data encoded with UTF-8 characters from Scandinavian languages.

Answer (score 0):

After searching i found solution for this case:
You should Add
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=Cp1256");
instead of:
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
in   <% DisplayProperty .....>     line

for benefit

Answer (score 0):

We are using DisplayTag 1.1.1 and we had a problem with special character encoding (UTF-8) in Excel/CSV export.  After some search's we were able to fix the issue by adding BOM before export string to writeExport() in TableTag.java class.

Ex:

JspWriter lOut = pageContext.getOut();

...

lOut.write('\ufeff');

lOut.write(pExportString);

This works well (display special characters correctly) except in xls output, all data displayed in one cell in Excel 2010 although CSV output displayed correctly. \t - TAB separator didn't work after adding BOM. But if we replace \t with Comma(,), it works as expected in Excel 2010.